# SAML Redirect request should be initiated from registered domain?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, adfs

In SAML Redirect request should be initiated from registered domain for testing purpose I am initiated from web browser .

Adfs doesn't accept my saml request

## SAML REQUEST

```
< samlp: AuthnRequest
xmlns: samlp = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
xmlns: saml = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
ID = "aaf23196-1773-2113-474a-fe114412ab72"
Version = "2.0"
IssueInstant = "2021-09-10T14:52:21Z"
AssertionConsumerServiceIndex = "0"
AttributeConsumingServiceIndex = "0" >
< saml: Issuer > http: // localhost: 4200 < / saml: Issuer >
< samlp: NameIDPolicy
Format = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" / >
< / samlp: AuthnRequest >
```

DEFLATE + BASE64 encoded saml request

https://saml.mlads.***.app/adfs/ls?SAMLRequest=hZHBSsQwEIbvfYqh92ybbLVsqIXiIiyoiCsevGXb1A2kyZqZyvr2pl0FUdHr5Pv+If9UgGqwBwnNSHt3r19GjZQcB+tQnp7gAtIxOOkVGpRODRoltXLb3FxLscjlIXjyrbfpV+s/SSHqQMa7NNmsJ1ipXiz56pzxslwywfmSFWWhWK85Lwou1K4UafKoA0ZpEmJKdBFHvXFIytE8zAVn+Yrx/IEX8kxIwZ/SpPlcdukdjoMOWx1eTRvFTh8nLSY1RMHsRtInxrjnnxDUSTX/TsK8OEANe6JYXpaB9a2ye48koRB5DhVk39gPOeK3sY/N+s5b074lVz4Miv4qjC/4PDEd62dY6kEZ23Rd0IhpXDRlZ79dEup3

I am initiating to IDP request by web browser url box instead of redirecting from the application because of that am I getting error like

" Invalid data while decoding " but the same data can be decoded using online tool

Comment: This question is quite unclear. Could you try and clarify?

Comment: @StefanRasmusson I updated pls check. is that adfs check strict origin if this redirect request  initiated from localhost application will it work?

Answer (score 1):

> " Invalid data while decoding " but the same data can be decoded using online tool

The request that you shared leads to the following XML piece:

```xml
< samlp: AuthnRequest
xmlns: samlp = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
xmlns: saml = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
ID = "aaf23196-1773-2113-474a-fe114412ab72"
Version = "2.0"
IssueInstant = "2021-09-10T14:52:21Z"
AssertionConsumerServiceIndex = "0"
AttributeConsumingServiceIndex = "0" >
< saml: Issuer > http: // localhost: 4200 < / saml: Issuer >
< samlp: NameIDPolicy
Format = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" / >
< / samlp: AuthnRequest >
```

Maybe the online tool is wrong, or maybe you shared a bad example; As you can see, this is clearly malformed.

Even then, "invalid data" can mean any number of things. Maybe the XML is bad, maybe it's missing a specific field, or a value, or maybe it needs to skip and ignore a specific field or value. Maybe your issuer is wrong, maybe the request must be signed. Invalid can be anything.

If possible, you should look at server logs to find the root cause with more detail, or look at a valid request that does work with ADFS and try to mimic that in your own flow.

Comment: Actually it works I failed to encode url after deflate and base64 encoded